# Error 'variable is undefined' when calling a function

Tags: asp-classic

I have created a classic asp page with a function like the following:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Option Explicit %>

<%
      <!--#INCLUDE file='ADOVBS.inc'-->
       Response.Buffer = True

%>
<%
      Function Lettergrade(lg)

             Dim lgs
             if lg>50 then
            set    lgs="P"
                else
            set    lgs="F"
             end if
           set Lettergrade= lgs
       End Function
  %>
<%
set strlettergrade=Lettergade(strgrade)
... other code goes here
%>
```

I'm trying to call the function in an expression but when it gives me the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4'
>
> Variable is undefined: 'Lettergade'

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5):

1. **Option Explicit** means you must DIM variables before they can be used.
2. **<!--#INCLUDE file='ADOVBS.inc'-->** is not vbscript so do not include them between the <% %> script delimiter tags.
3. You need to **DIM strgrade**
4. you need to **DIM strlettergrade** before you use it
5. Fix the typo of Lettergade(strgrade)

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %> 
<% Option Explicit %>  
<% Response.Buffer = True %>

<!--#INCLUDE file='ADOVBS.inc'-->

<%
Dim strlettergrade
Dim strgrade

%>

<%
Function Lettergrade(lg)

if lg > 50 then
  Lettergrade ="P" 
else 
  Lettergrade ="F" 

End Function
%>

<%
strgrade = 75
strlettergrade=Lettergrade(strgrade)
... other code goes here 
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the `Set` inside the function call and just assign `Lettergrade = lgs`.

Answer (score 1):

`Variable is undefined: 'Lettergade'`

Function appears to be called `Lettergrade` not `Lettergade` - might just be a typo issue

Try changing:

`strlettergrade=Lettergade(strgrade)`

to

`strlettergrade=Lettergrade(strgrade)`

Comment: That is right. Thank you so much. Been with this error from last night.

Comment: After changing this your code worked? Wow, you sure inserted a lot of decoy errors in your questions then ;).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this script, some already pointed out by Chris and Ryan.

1. You only need `Set` when you assign an object to a variable. Strings are not objects in VBScript. Get rid of all the `Set`'s in your script.
2. The obvious typo that Chris mentioned. Change `Lettergade` to `Lettergrade`.
3. You don't seem to declare the `strlettergrade` or `strGrade` variable. With `Option Explicit` turned on (which is a good practice), it is mandatory to declare **all** variables. Use `Dim` for this (like the one inside your function).
4. You seem to use a string as a parameter for your `Lettergrade` function. Since the variable name is `strgrade`. Within the function you are comparing with an `integer`. This *could* cause problems. Convert your string to an integer first using the `cInt` function.
5. Includes need to go outside the `<% %>` tags. Move `<!--#INCLUDE file='ADOVBS.inc'-->` to the line below `Option Explicit`

Follow these steps, or copy paste the script from @Cape Cod Gunny. After this your script should work as expected ;). Except for point 4, you still need to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled Lettergrade when calling the function.  Variable is undefined: '**Lettergade**'  Also I would take SLaks advice as well.  Set should not be used on strings.